# Solve this error message : please double check the project key and sonar url

Tags: angular, typescript, sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-vs

I want to use Sonar Lint plugin in VS Code to scan and analyse the Type Script code in Angular project.
I installed Sonar Lint plugin `version 1.15.0` and added this conf inside the `settings.json` file :

```
{
"sonarlint.connectedMode.connections.sonarqube": [

    { 
        "connectionId": "mySonar",
        "serverUrl": "http://host:8080/server", 
        "token": "myToken" 
    }
],
"sonarlint.connectedMode.project": {
    "connectionId": "mySonar",
    "projectKey": "DEV-SONAR"
    }
}
```

After that, I installed Sonar Qube plugin and generated the `project.json` file in `.vscode` folder with this config :

```
{
   "project": "DEV-SONAR",
   "sonarURL": "http://host:8080/server"
}
```

In VS Code, I used `CTRL+P` and I put this :

[image]

The result is :

[image]

But when I put :

[image]

I get this error :

[image]

How can I resolve this problem ?

Comment: Hi, were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this probleme by deleting `"project": "DEV-SONAR",` in `project.json` file